# Unable to get my "Save" Button to work, my button does nothing when pressed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a note taking app, however, I'm kinda stuck on how to get my save button to work. Here's what I've got so far:

My Add "Item" View

```
class AddViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var addShortDescription: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var addLongDescription: UITextView!
    
    public var completion: ((String, String) -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addShortDescription.becomeFirstResponder()
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didTapSave))
            self.title = "Add New Item"
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapSave(_ sender: Any) {
        if let text = addShortDescription.text, !text.isEmpty, !addLongDescription.text.isEmpty {
            completion?(text, addLongDescription.text)
        }
    }

}
```

My Main View

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    
    var models: [(ShortDescription: String, LongDescription: String)] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        self.title = "Inventory"
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].ShortDescription
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].LongDescription
        return cell
    }
    
    @IBAction func addNewInventory(){
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "add") as? AddViewController else {
            return
        }
        vc.title = "Add New Item"
        vc.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        vc.completion = { addShortDescription, addLongDescription in
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            self.models.append((ShortDescription: addShortDescription, LongDescription: addLongDescription))
            self.table.isHidden = false
            self.table.reloadData()
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let model = models[indexPath.row]

        // Show addLongDescription controller
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "inventory") as?
            EditViewController else {
            return
        }
        vc.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        vc.title = "Edit Item"
        vc.addShortDescription.text = model.ShortDescription
        vc.addLongDescription.text = model.LongDescription
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

I have another view where I plan on allowing the user to edit the added items, I'll add that if you think it may be causing some problems.

Comment: What's the actual problem? You do what, and what happens, and what do you expect? What ever it is, did you debug (i.e. step thru the code)? If so, what did you discover?

Comment: It’s suppose to add a short description (title) and long description (the subtitle) into the var models when I press save. I have a ibaction that suppose to respond to when the save button is pressed but when I press save in the sim nothing happens. Going through the code I believe it should work but I’m obviously doing something wrong. I’m still pretty new to swift, it could be something with my storyboard. Would I need to add an iboutlet to my save button in my add view to make it work?

Comment: The question is not a visual one but a technical one. Put a breakpoint at the start of the function that the button is supposed to run. Tap the button. Do you pause at the breakpoint? If so, step one line at a time and see what the code actually does.